# JavaFX - Timeline Animation Object not Displaying?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to JavaFX, and I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here.
I'm trying to make an animation of a car that travels from left to right across a window, wrapping around the right side when it gets there. The user should be able to hit up/down to adjust the speed of the animation. I had the animation going when I used a `PathTransition` object, but found out you can't adjust the `Duration` of a `PathTransition`, so I redid it in a `Timeline`.

With `Timeline`, though, I'm stuck. The car does not display on the screen when I launch the application. Here's what I'm hoping is a concise code snippet:

```
public class Project12 extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {     
    //Create Pane to hold the car animation
    Pane pane = new Pane();

    //Create the RaceCarPane
    RaceCarPane raceCar = new RaceCarPane();
    pane.getChildren().add(raceCar); //Adds the race car to the main pane

    //Create the VBox to hold components
    VBox displayPane = new VBox();
    displayPane.getChildren().addAll(pane, userInstructions, btnPause);
    displayPane.setSpacing(15);
    displayPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    //Create scene for display and add the display pane
    Scene scene = new Scene(displayPane);

    //Add the scene to the stage and display
    primaryStage.setTitle("Project 12");
    primaryStage.setResizable(false); //disable resizing of the window
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

And the RaceCarPane:

```
public class RaceCarPane extends Pane {

    //Declare origin for determining polygon point locations
    private double originX = 10;
    private double originY = getHeight() - 10;
    private Timeline carAnimation;

    //Set the Timeline for the car in constructor method
    public RaceCarPane() {
        carAnimation = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(100), e -> moveCar()));
        carAnimation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        carAnimation.play();
    }

    private void paint() {

        //Create a polygon for the body 
        Polygon body = new Polygon();
        body.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        body.setStroke(Color.DARKBLUE);


        //Add points to the body
        ObservableList<Double> bodyList = body.getPoints();

        /*(code omitted, just adding coordinates to the ObservableList for all parts. 
        I don't believe the bug is here since it displayed when I was using a PathTransition animation)*/

        //Add to pane
        getChildren().addAll(body, roof, frontWheel, rearWheel);
    }

    public void setOrigin (double x, double y) {
        this.originX = x;
        this.originY = y;
    }

    @Override
    public void setWidth(double width) {
        super.setWidth(width);
        paint();
    }

    @Override
    public void setHeight(double height) {
        super.setHeight(height);;
        paint();
    }

    public void moveCar() {
        //Check that car is in bounds
        if(originX <= getWidth()) {
            originX += 10;
            paint();
        }
        else {
            originX = 0;
            paint();
        }
```

EDIT: Per @Jai's comment below, my solution was to revert to the `PathTransition` object and use its `RateProperty` bound to a `SimpleDoubleProperty`. While maybe not what the project was looking for as a solution, it does the trick, so I'm happy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@swpalmer was right to say that you shouldn't add it repeatedly.

That aside, you could definitely use `PathTransition` by using [`Animation.rateProperty()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Animation.html#rateProperty) (`PathTransition` extends `Animation`).

Also, from [`PathTransition`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/PathTransition.html):

> This Transition creates a path animation that spans its duration. The
>   translation along the path is done by updating the **`translateX`** and
>   **`translateY`** variables of the node, and the rotate variable will get
>   updated if orientation is set to
>   OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT, at regular interval.

Therefore, if you are using `Timeline`, you should also be setting the `translateX` and `translateY` of the whole node (i.e. `RaceCarPane`) to perform the animation; trying to add polygons repeatedly is definitely the wrong approach. If you were also adding a lot of polygons when you were using `PathTransition`, you were probably not doing it quite right as well. Even when the animation turns out to be visually correct, it doesn't always mean that it is done correctly.

Comment: Hmm. While I looked into the documentation for `PathTransition` I didn't think to check out what I could do from `Animation.` If I can use `ObservableRate` and just update the rate value instead of the immutable `Duration`, then I should be golden.  I'll give this a shot tomorrow and update if it does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: it works! Still no idea why `Timeline` wouldn't work for me, but using `PathTransition` and then adjusting its `rateProperty` per a `SimpleDoubleProperty` does the trick. Now I can wrap this up and finally get to studying for next week's finals, haha...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you missed a closing brace in the paint method.

There are a few things "wrong".  For one, you should not be creating new objects and adding them to the scene graph every time you want to move your car.  You;ve also left out how you use originX, originY.

I suggest you use a Group to hold the parts of the car.  Add it once to the RaceCarPane and use a transform on the group object to move it.

This would probably be easier if you based in on an AnimationTimer instead of a Timeline, particularly if you want to be able to dynamically adjust the speed of the car.

Comment: I missed that closing brace when I was editing out unnecessary code. Those edits were where I used originX/Y - they're just used as origin points for determining how my Polygon shapes to build the car come from. 

The car drew just fine when I was using `PathTransition` so I'm 90% sure that my problem isn't with drawing the car itself.

I can look into an AnimationTimer, but that's not covered in our textbook so I can only assume that I'm supposed to figure out how to do this with Timeline.

Comment: @meyer9168 Modifying coordinates in your Polygon is not the right way to do this.  You want to define a static object using fixed points for the polygon that is shaped like a car and then move where that is drawn as a group. You want one car node in the scene graph hierarchy that you translate as needed.